# Cannot decode null into a string type

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to decode a struct which contains a result field, where the result field is either a null or string value. I'm trying to decode this into a string pointer but I get the error:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Result   *string `json:"result,omitempty" bson:"result"`
}
```

The bson/json is something like:

```
{"result" : null}
```

or

```
{"result" : "somedata"}
```

Decode with:

```
var result MyStruct

err := collection.FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(&result)
if err != nil {
    s.logFile.Fatal(err)
}
```

Error:

```
cannot decode null into a string type
```

I'm using the official driver: "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo" & "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/x/bsonx"

Comment: Far better is avoid null. Empty string is better than pointer.

Comment: Your code should work rightfully. It looks the unmarshaling process is not the reverse of the marshaling process. The official MongoDB driver is in **alpha** phase. Report this at their site and hope they make this work sometime in the future.

Comment: Why are you traying to have point to stirng. I think your problem may solve if you use  Result   string

Comment: I'm parsing data from another teams mongodb, and I think they do it because the value wasn't set, instead of it being set but empty. I'll make a ticket on the mongo driver GitHub. Thanks

Comment: You can try like this https://play.golang.org/p/K6Nlhg3LN5W.

Comment: do you have a link to the ticket?